# Where can I find a List of the top 10,000 keyword search queries

Tags: keywords, search

Where can I find a List of the top 10,000 keyword search queries?

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: I think this is dependent on a lot of factors, including location and date/time, so I don't think you'll find anyone providing a list of 10 000.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Insights for Search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/) will give you the top 50 for a specific country, however, that's probably about as much as you'll get directly from a search engine.

**Edit:** You have to select the "Download as CSV" option to get all 50 searches (Insights is still in beta, though, so I'd expect some interface changes over time).